# Different layout for 5 and 4 inch Android devices

Tags: android, layout

I have an Android application with one layout file. I have different layout files for different densities, i.e., layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, etc. I also have different dimens files in corresponding value directories (values-mdpi, values-hdpi, etc).

My problem is that I would like to use different layouts for 4 and 5 inch screen devices. I am testing on two physical a 4 inch and a 5 inch and both devices use the layout from the /res/layout folder and the dimens file from the /res/values-hdpi/ folder (in other words, they use the same resources).

Is there a way to make the 4 inch device use a different dimens.xml file - if not automatically, can this be done programmatically?

Comment: hi there did you find solution or still need help

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `layout-sw320dp` or similar. This will differentiate layouts based on minimum display width.

Here is much more about it:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Answer (score 0):

Density is not related to size, they tell you how many pixels there are in on square inch of screen, not how may inches of space there are in the screen. you should use size related resources. for example `layout-w500dp` folder would be used for screens that have at least 500dp of width.
[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) should help